# При работе с файлами после каждой строки вставляются буквы М

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, файлы

После каждой строкий вставленой из файла в массив появляется лишняя строка состоящая из буквы М

```
char str[10][25],d;

in=fopen("file.txt", "r");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
    {
        fgets(str[i], 300, in);

    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
    {
        printf("%c",str[i][j]);

    }
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: А какие у вас концы строк в файле? И какая ОС?

Comment: переход на новую строку

Comment: А какой смысл заложен в первый цикл `for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум - у вас строка `str[i]` рассчитана на 25 символов, а вы готовы читать 300: `fgets(str[i], 300, in);`...

И какой смысл в цикле

```
for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
```

??

А тут -

```
printf("%c",str[i][j]);
```

вы выводите все, весь мусор! а не останавливаетесь по достижении завершающего нулевого символа...

Вобщем, попробуйте так:

```
char str[10][300];

FILE * in=fopen("file.txt", "rt");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    fgets(str[i], 300, in);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("%s",str[i]);
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: исправил
ничего не поменялось

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Comment: Ну, значит, помечайте ответ как принятый...